# Do $A=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2-z^2=1\}$ $B=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$ intersect transversally?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Consider the two regular submanifolds $A=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2-z^2=1\}$ $B=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I want to check if the intersect transverally, i.e, I want to check whether $\forall p\in A\cap B$, $T_pA+T_pB=T_p{\mathbb{R^3}}$. After some work, $$T_{(a,b,c)}A=\{(x,y,z)|ax+by-cz=0\}$$ $$T_{(a,b,c)}B=\{(x,y,z)|ax+by+cz=0\}$$

However, I do not know how to proceed from here onwards. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well, what about the point $(1,0,0)$? Then both tangent spaces coincide, so?

Comment: Proceeding naively: Subtracting them,
$z^2 = 0$.
Substituting this into each,
we see that
both contain
$x^2+y^2 = 1$,
a circle in the plane
$z = 0$. I don't know if this helps,
since I do not know
differential topology.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes then the tangent spaces are {(0,y,z)}. This is equal to the tangent space of $\mathbb{R^3}$ at $(1,0,0)$ right?

Comment: No, the tangent space of $\mathbb R^3$ at any given point is three dimensional.

Comment: I meant not equal. Yeah sure

Answer (score 0):

The intersection is the circle $x^2+y^2=1,$ $z=0.$ For any point $p=(a,b,0)$ in the intersection  you have

$$T_{(a,b,0)}A= T_{(a,b,0)}B=\{(x,y,z)\text{ | }ax+by=0\}.$$

Note that $T_x\mathbf{R}^3=\mathbf{R}^3$ for any $x \in \mathbf{R}^3.$ Thus the equation $T_{(a,b,0)}A+ T_{(a,b,0)}B=T_x\mathbf{R}^3=\mathbf{R}^3$ never holds for $p=(a,b,0)$ in the intersection (as $T_{(a,b,0)}A=T_{(a,b,0)}B$ is a 2-dimensional vector space), and hence the intersection is not transversal.